# mysql database from linux command line with dot in database name

Tags: mysql, linux, database

I have mysql database which has dot in database name

database name = "abc.domain.com"

my query for linux command line is

```
mysql -u"root" -p"123" -h 0 -e"USE information_schema;select column_name, column_type from information_schema.columns where TABLE_SCHEMA = `abc.domain.com` AND table_name=`bugs`;" | column -t > /tmp/describe
```

in above command I am writing database name in between backticks ``  it understand as linux command.

In mysql it is working fine.

how to solve this problem?

Comment: Try escaping the backticks - the shell may be intercepting them.  Use \` ? - sorry I can't test right now.

Comment: Your backticks in the select statement should be single-quotes. And even better, rename your schema to something without a dot. That's the worst character you could use in the name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/bin/sh -c mysql -u"root" -p"123" -h 0 -e"USE information_schema;select column_name, column_type from information_schema.columns where TABLE_SCHEMA = \\\`abc.domain.com\\\` AND table_name=\\\`bugs\\\`;" | column -t > /tmp/describe
```

Or

```
    $ export F='USE information_schema;select column_name, column_type from information_schema.columns where TABLE_SCHEMA = `abc.domain.com` AND table_name=`bugs`;'
    $ printenv F
    USE information_schema;select column_name, column_type from information_schema.columns where TABLE_SCHEMA = `abc.domain.com` AND table_name=`bugs`;
   /bin/sh -c mysql -u"root" -p"123" -h 0 -e $F | column -t > /tmp/describe
```

EDIT1:

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

It's not advisable to use root without password [How to Reset the Root Password](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html)

Comment: it show error ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: Please try it on ubuntu machine

Comment: bash: syntax error near unexpected token `column_type'

Comment: if the first one give you an "using password: NO" error you have just to set your password..